# Preventing tsc compiler from omitting the unnecessary external modules

Tags: requirejs, typescript

There's a feature in TypeScript which I like so much and that's external modules using RequireJs and that the fact that the compiler won't include imported modules unless they are actually needed in the code. Here's an example:

```
import A = require('./A');
import B = require('./B');

var a = new A();
```

When you compile the above code using `tsc --module amd example.ts` it will transcompile to:

```
define(["require", "exports", './A'], function(require, exports, A) {
    var a = new A();
});
```

As you can see there's no sign of `B` in the generated code. That's because `B` was not actually used. As I said this feature is great but now I've got a scenario in which I need to include some of the external modules even though they are not actually used anywhere in the code.

Does anyone have any idea how to do that? To prevent any misunderstanding, I'm not looking for a way to disable this feature completely, just for some specific modules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way to do it:

```
/// <amd-dependency path="./B" />
import A = require('./A');
```

No need to create fictitious code

Comment: +1 This is a neat feature, but remember, it hasn't made it into the TypeScript language specification yet so there are no guarantees it will remain in the compiler (although it seems unlikely that it would be removed).

Answer (score 1):

There is a simply fiddle you can do to get the compiler to include both:

```
import A = require('./A');
import B = require('./B');

var a = new A();
var b = B;
```

The variable `b` becomes noise in your program, so I wouldn't use this technique too much, but if the `B` module is doing polyfills or something like that which means you'll never want to directly instantiate it, this gets it loaded for you.

Comment: I appreciate your help but unfortunately that's not acceptable. Because this solution is not always feasible. Instantiating `B` might trigger some action which I can't / don't want to take lightly. It might do something that needs to be done on the need to be done basis.

Comment: You haven't instantiated it. You have created a reference to it. To instantiate `B` you would use `var b = new B();`, whereas `var b = B` simply creates a reference to `B` called `b`.