# Force Typescript to require the file even though it's not used directly

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm doing Angular coding using Typescript, and because Angular do the loading of modules for me, all I have is imports at the top of my file like this:

```typescript
import User = require('modules/user');
import Login = require('modules/login');

module Base {

   module Services {

      export class UserState {
         static $inject: string[] = ['$user'];

         constructor(private $user: User.Services.$user){ }
      }
   }

   angular.module('Base', ['User', 'Login']).service('UserState', Services.UserState);
}

export = Base;
```

this would create the module "Base" and already loaded `user.ts` and `login.ts` files, but that's not the case. Because I'm not using any of the exports from User and Login, the generated Base module is:

```javascript
var Base;
(function (Base) {
  var Services;
  (function(Services){
    var UserState = (function () {
        function UserState($user) {
            this.$user = $user;
        }
        UserState.$inject = ['$user'];
        return UserState;
    })();
    Services.UserState = UserState;         
  })(Services || (Services = {}));

  angular.module('Base', ['User', 'Login']).service('UserState', Services.UserState);
})(Base || (Base = {}));

module.exports = Base;
```

how to force typescript to include CommonJS require calls without the need to reference the files?

Comment: Search for similar questions containing `<amd-dependency`

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327306/preventing-tsc-compiler-from-omitting-the-unnecessary-external-modules/26380782#26380782